# How to Seal leaks on an air compressor system

Tags: compressor, leaks

My air compressor machine is leaking at its clamped joint area where the red plastic tubing is connected to a metal joint.

I see products on the market meant to seal leaks such as teflon tape and pro-dope pipe thread sealant, but it seems like both of these are only for use with piping that is threaded. This piping is not threaded and is just held together by the clamped joint, is there any other products on the market that anyone would recommend? Or would one of those other products also work in this situation??

Thanks

Comment: Can you include a photo?

Comment: Is this a red rubber air line for air tools, or some other applications? Sometimes those rubber air hoses can age and become brittle, making it nearly impossible to seal.

Answer (score 1):

Rubber (better, usually) or plastic tubing on a barbed joint is not a suitable place for any sort of sealant, and none should be required.

If the tubing is cracked, either cut off enough tubing to remove the cracked end (if it's just at the end) or replace it.

Otherwise, push the tubing fully onto the barbed fitting and tighten the clamp(s) - in some cases adding a second hose clamp with the clamping mechanism rotated from the first hose clamp (so if one has the clamp screw at 3 o'clock the other would have it at 9 o'clock) may help - often the barbed fitting is long, and clamp used is short.

Oversized clamps wound down too small may have excessive not-roundness near the clamping mechanism; a properly sized one will work better in that case.